# Avoiding DRY by merging functions

Tags: jquery, dry

In my code I have to divs with different names, except the last part of the names that's the same (successMessage). When the div(s) appears in the code below is executed removing the div(s) after 1 second.

Of course, this is a good example of DRY because the functions is the same except for the name of the divs. So, what is the easiest way to merge these functions to one that affects both divs?

Thanks in advance!

```
    if ($('#MainContent_MovieEdit_MovieGenreEdit1_successMessage').length > 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#MainContent_MovieEdit_MovieGenreEdit1_successMessage').fadeOut('slow');
        }, 1000);
    };

    if ($('#MainContent_MovieEdit_successMessage').length > 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#MainContent_MovieEdit_successMessage').fadeOut('slow');
        }, 1000);
    };
```

Comment: Why not add a `successMessage` class and select with that instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#MainContent_MovieEdit_successMessage, #MainContent_MovieEdit_MovieGenreEdit1_successMessage')
 .delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
```

There is no need for the `if` statement, if jQuery couldn't find the elements, nothing will happen. The [*multiple selector* <sup>[docs]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) will select both elements and [`.delay()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) offers a nice way to defer the execution of `fadeOut`.

Another possible selector would be the [*attribute starts with selector* <sup>[docs]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('div[id^="MainContent_MovieEdit_"]')
```

assuming the elements are `div` elements. Of course you can also wrap this in a function if you really wanted to:

```
function fadeOut($elements) {
    $elements.delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
}

fadeOut($('div[id^="MainContent_MovieEdit_"]'));
```

Comment: Great, thanks alot. Didn't know that the if statement wasn't necessary. You learn something new everyday :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function setFade(divId) {
    var element = $('#' + divId);
    if (element.length > 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            element.fadeOut('slow');
        }, 1000);
    };
}
```

Extract a method

---

Or maybe better yet use a html class.

```
var elements = $('.to-fade');
if (elements.length > 0) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        elements.fadeOut('slow');
    }, 1000);
};
```

Comment: You should probably cache the jquery object in a `var` at the start of the function to be DRYer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use attribute starts with selector

```
if ($('div[id^=MainContent_MovieEdit]').length > 0) {
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(that).fadeOut('slow');
    }, 1000);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As best practice you should also only find your dom element once:
so instead of querying the dom twice, you can do the following:

```
var $successMessage = $('#MainContent_MovieEdit_MovieGenreEdit1_successMessage');
if ($successMessage.length > 0) {
     // etc.
    $successMessage.fadeOut();
}
```